SSIS Slowly Changing Dimension not displaying any connection in the Connection Managers using Oracle SQL
I'm encountering an issue in SSIS when trying to set up a Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) in a Data Flow task. Here's the problem:

I have an OLE DB Source that connects to an Oracle SQL database.
When I link the OLE DB Source to the SCD component and open the SCD
wizard, no connection appear in the connection manager drop-down
menu.
I've tried using both project-level and non-project-level
connections, but the wizard still doesn’t recognize or display any
connections.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? How can I resolve it?
Additionally, if there’s no straightforward fix, does anyone know a good alternative?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
